# Use ciphers to rescue your friend

Tags: cipher

Your friend Puzzle has been kidnapped by a mysterious group of people. A few days after the capture you receive a mysterious email:

> Dear Sexaginta Quattuor,
>
> $\qquad$TXkgdHdvLXllYXItb2xkIHNvbiBsb292ZWVzc3NzIGJhY29uISBXaGVuIGhlIGVhdHMgaXQgaGUgc2F5cywgIkFBQkFCQkFBQUFBQUJBQUFBQkFBQkFBQkFBQUJBQUJBQkFCQkFBQkFBQUJCQkFCQkFCQkFBQUJCQUFCQUFBQUJBQUJCQUJBQkFCQkFCQUFBQkFBQkFBQUJCQkJBQUFBQUFCQUFBQUJBQUFBQUJBQUFCQUFCQUJCQUJBQUFBQkFBQkFBQUJCQkJBQUFBQUFCQUFBQUJBQUJBQUJCQUJCQUFBQUJCQSI=
>
> $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$ Respectfully Signed,$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$01010000011101010111101001111010011011000110010100001101

Comment: Are there any indications to how to solve it?

Comment: The binary at the end simply translates to 'Puzzle'. Also, 'Sexaginta Quattuor' means 64 in Latin.

Comment: @boboquack I would like to see if anyone can solve it without any hints.

Comment: Not sure why a downvote. The puzzle is just fine with clues given.

Comment: @Techidot Some people don't like external links.

Comment: @boboquack Doesn't mean it has to be downvoted. Also, some very good puzzles have hosted stuff here and there. And there is a very tiny part hosted I guess. :)

Comment: @Techidiot I agree. However I've seen enough complaints to be able to guess what people are thinking when they downvote (on an average sample of the population of PSE) :D

Comment: @boboquack Yeah. It's just a matter of choice :) Anyways, this one was a good and fun one! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **Final**

Friend puzzle is located at -

> ***Lincoln County, NV, USA***

**Steps**

> As will pointed out *Sexaginta Quarttuor is 64* in Latin. Hence decoding the following with **base64** we get 
>  *My two-year-old son looveessss bacon! When he eats it he says, "AABABBAAAAAABAAAABAABAABAAABAABABABBAABAAABBBABBABBAAABBAABAAAABAABBABABABBABAAABAABAAABBBBAAAAAABAAAABAAAAABAAABAABABBABAAAABAABAAABBBBAAAAAABAAAABAABAABBABBAAAABBA"*

**Now**

> It say's bacon. It's a Baconian cipher. Decoding it with I=J and U=V we get 
>  *FREE TEXT HOST COM I THREE CEYR THREE UNG* Which is nothing but some URL of the text hosted at [Free Text Host](http://freetexthost.com/)

**Then,**

> Converting I->J and U->V we get [this link](http://freetexthost.com/j3ceyr3vng) giving us
>  01001001 00100000 01100001 01101101 00100000 01100100 01101111 01101001 01101110 01100111 00100000 01100110 01101001 01101110 01100101 00100000 01101001 01101110 00100000 01101101 01111001 00100000 01101110 01100101 01110111 00100000 01100110 01101111 01110101 01110010 00101101 01101100 01100101 01110110 01100101 01101100 00100000 01101000 01101111 01101101 01100101 00101100 00100000 01100010 01110101 01110100 00100000 01110100 01101000 01100101 01110010 01100101 00100000 01101001 01110011 00100000 01100001 00100000 01110010 01100001 01101001 01101100 00100000 01100110 01100101 01101110 01100011 01100101 00100000 01100001 01110010 01101111 01110101 01101110 01100100 00100000 01101001 01110100 00101110 00100000 01001001 00100000 01101100 01101001 01101011 01100101 00100000 01111010 01101001 01100111 01111010 01100001 01100111 01100111 01101001 01101110 01100111 00100000 01100110 01110010 01101111 01101101 00100000 01110100 01101000 01100101 00100000 01100010 01101111 01110100 01110100 01101111 01101101 00100000 01101111 01100110 00100000 01101101 01111001 00100000 01101000 01101111 01110101 01110011 01100101 00100000 01100001 01101100 01101100 00100000 01110100 01101000 01100101 00100000 01110111 01100001 01111001 00100000 01110101 01110000 00101110 00100000 01001001 00100000 01101000 01100001 01110110 01100101 00100000 01100001 00100000 01101110 01100101 01110111 00100000 01100011 01101111 01101101 01110000 01110101 01110100 01100101 01110010 00111011 00100000 01110100 01101000 01100101 00100000 01110000 01100001 01110011 01110011 01110111 01101111 01110010 01100100 00100000 01101001 01110011 00100000 00110010 00110001 00111001 00101110 00110011 00110001 00110101 00110110 00111001 00110111 00110111 00111011 00101110 00110000 00111001 00110011 01001110 00111000 0101011

**Which gives -**

> The binary is malformed. Adding an extra 1 at the end and then converting binary to text we get - *"I am doing fine in my new four-level home, but there is a rail fence around it. I like zigzagging from the bottom of my house all the way up. I have a new computer; the password is 219.3156977;.093N8W"*

**Further**

> This is a Rail-Fence cipher with Level-4 and zigzagging bottom to up. Decoding it gives 37.237N;115.806999W(Thanks to @M Oehm for the right decoding)

**So,**

> The friend has been captured and is located at **Lincoln County, NV, USA**(According to [this](http://www.latlong.net/Show-Latitude-Longitude.html))

**Visual**

> Somewhere here in the fields! :)
>  [image]

Comment: You almost got the link, but you made a mistake when decoding the Bacon cipher

Comment: @suomynonA  Isn't it "ITHREECEYRTHREEUNG" ?

Comment: No; but you are very close

Comment: @suomynonA  If you try decoding *"AABABBAAAAAABAAAABAABAABAAABAABABABBAABAAABBBABBABBAAABBAABAAAABAABBABABABBABAAABAABAAABBBBAAAAAABAAAABAAAAABAAABAABABBABAAAABAABAAABBBBAAAAAABAAAABAABAABBABBAAAABBA"* with bacon you get **FREETEXTHOSTCOMITHREECEYRTHREEUNG** Not sure what am I missing here? :-/

Comment: Maybe try switching it up (don't want to give out the answer right away)

Comment: Hint: change all the i's into j's and all the u's into ___'s

Comment: typically you should be waiting at least 2 days to actually post a hint..

Comment: @suomynonA It's done. I almost forgot to convert the letters.

Comment: @MOehm Yeah. Now I got it. And its still partial :) There was a malformed binary at the end. An extra 0 was required to complete it.

Comment: I guess it's an axtra 1, so that the last letter is W. (It looks like a railfenced long/lat coordinate.)

Comment: @MOehm Yeah. N73217805169W399 this is what I have. Checking if there is any co-ord here

Comment: I've got 37.237N;115.806999W, which is just north of Las Vegas. Not sure what to make of that, though.

Comment: @MOehm That's it. That should be the final answer :) Thanks

Comment: @suomynonA Hope that's what you are looking for :)

Comment: Nice job; you got it!